# How to check pnpm strict-peer-dependencies (ERR_PNPM_PEER_DEP_ISSUES) when "Lockfile is up to date"?

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, pnpm

When I add dependency without it's peerDependency in empty project by editing package.json like:

```
{
  "name": "pnpmtest",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.0"
  }
}
```

and then run

```
pnpm install
```

Command will output error **`ERR_PNPM_PEER_DEP_ISSUES`**

```
devDependencies:
+ eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y 6.6.1

 ERR_PNPM_PEER_DEP_ISSUES  Unmet peer dependencies

.
└─┬ eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y 6.6.1
  └── ✕ missing peer eslint@"^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7 || ^8"
Peer dependencies that should be installed:
  eslint@"^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7 || ^8"
```

Above command output `1` exit code.

```
echo $?
1
```

This error is perfectly fine since my project is missing eslint. This is desired output.

My problem starts in CI environment where I would also like to see this error after `pnpm install` and break CI pipeline. Currently when I remove `node_modules` and run above install once again (this is simulation what is happening in CI) I **do not see error and command output code 0**.

```
→ rm -rf node_modules

→ pnpm install
Lockfile is up to date, resolution step is skipped
Packages: +56
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Packages are hard linked from the content-addressable store to the virtual store.
  Content-addressable store is at: /Users/mjanaszek/Library/pnpm/store/v3
  Virtual store is at:             node_modules/.pnpm
Progress: resolved 56, reused 56, downloaded 0, added 56, done

devDependencies:
+ eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y 6.6.1

→ echo $?
0
```

How to check in CI environment (when "Lockfile is up to date") if my dependencies contains some **ERR_PNPM_PEER_DEP_ISSUES**?

Comment: Looks like there is already a feature request open for this: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/discussions/5384 . A hack can be to write a script that copies package.json to a temp dir and runs pnpm install there and see if there are any errors.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the status of the packages by running `pnpm ls --json`.

If you don't want pnpm to fail on peer dependency issues, set the "strict-peer-dependencies" setting to "false".

`pnpm up --config.strict-peer-dependencies=false`

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: The question is how to specifically check for peer warnings, not suppress them.